# How/Why do amulets work?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, segulah, practical-kabbalah

Assuming that kameot (Jewish amulets) do provide some real protection (not simply putting the mind of the wearer at ease) how/why do they work? Meaning, why would writing the various obscure names of God, angels and abbreviations of verses which are then worn by someone prevent the wearer from harm?

Comment: What kind of answer are you hoping for here?  Isn't this a little like asking "how does davening for a refua shelaima heal a person?"

Comment: @yoel maybe it's just that simple ie it works because chazal say it works. i'm curious if there is something more. perhaps like a mezuzah where harmful forces see the name of God and are afraid or not giving dominion to harm. or if wearing these various names gives a person spiritual abilities she wouldn't otherwise have. basically i'm looking for a better understanding of the underlying principles - if there are none then i would accept that answer (sourced) as well.

Comment: Why do you assume that they do work in some other manner than psychologically helping the person?

Comment: `...like a mezuzah where harmful forces see the name of God and are afraid or not giving dominion to harm.` Umm... where did you get that from?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but there is a section on written amulets [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/jms/jms12.htm), and [Kraig's Modern Magick](http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Magick-Twelve-Lessons-Magickal/dp/0738715786) has a lot to say about the how-to aspect of it. He may discuss theory; I'm not certain.

Comment: [Gemoro Shabbos 61b](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/shabbos/insites/sh-dt-061.htm ) discusses the effectiveness of amulets which can be established either by the experience of using the text or ingredients of the amulet or by the experience of the expert who made it. 

So it seems that it may work either as a result of the specific formulation or as a result of the spiritual  powers of the expert.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are undervaluing the impact that the wearer's mind has on the effect of the amulet. For the sake of the argument let's just say that the amulet is a placebo. Most people erroneously think that placebos don't work. And that's not actually the case, placebo's DO work, but it's not because of anything inherent to the placebo.

The placebo effect is a real effect, and people do often have better outcomes when given a placebo vs those who are given nothing. The effect of the placebo may be entirely mental, but it doesn't change the fact that the efficacy is real and proveable.

So even if an amulet is just a placebo, it can have real impact on a person who wears it beyond it just being "in their head."

Answer (score -2):

If you light a match to an amulet it burns. If it cannot protect itself how much more could it not protect you? To place trust in amulets is idolatry.

Comment: I agree that amulets don't work, but note that a smoke detector will also catch on fire if you put a match to it.

Comment: A smoke detector does not protect people from fire. Rather, it warns the person to put out the fire.

Comment: I sympathise with your answer. But, as I comment above [Gemoro Shabbos 61b](dafyomi.co.il/shabbos/insites/sh-dt-061.htm ) discusses the effectiveness of amulets. It does not mention that to place trust in amulets is idolatry!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Thank you for your comment. Rabbi Moshe Ben Chaim of Mesora dot org writes that it is idolatry to think that the amulet itself has magical powers as only G-d is all-powerful.

Comment: Yes. It is idolatry to think that *anything* has powers other than Hashem Yisborach.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Yes. We agree.

Answer (score -3):

The metaphysical realm is just as much a reality as the physical realm... There are lots of things to prove it, whether the many stories of malachim in Tanach or the famous mekubalim. While these things generally aren't our mesorah, just because the idea seems abstract it doesn't mean they are fake.

For example see the examples of amulets written by Reb Shaya’le of Kerestir, [here](https://www.ravlehoishia.org/miracle_amulet) and [here](https://www.ravlehoishia.org/story1).

Comment: Thank you for answering but this site encourages people to back up their point with Torah sources.

Comment: A quick readthrough of Bereishis should suffice...

Comment: So bring some pesukim into your answer to give it more support...

Comment: @dov Sure but seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: At the moment this answer is more suited as a comment, for it to still stand as an answer it needs some scriptural sources as it is a throwaway comment

Comment: @Dov added it in.......................................